# EF Core - Clear __EFMigrationsHistories table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to clear this table: __EFMigrationsHistories

I don't want to delete my migration or something, I explicitly want to clear this table by code.

Edit:

I would try to explain a little bit why i want to do this! I want to call on every startup the same (and the only one) migration.

And this migration loops trough all my models and call's the onUpdateMethod, so every model can handle his update by itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That table is used by the migrations tracking code so clearing it could cause all sorts of fun and interesting issues.

Comment: execute simple query in your sql server -> DELETE FROM table_name

Comment: @Valkyriee I wish to do this in my c# application

Comment: here is using entity framework : context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");

Comment: @Flo do you understand the implication of doing this? Bad things will happen!

Comment: @DavidG warnings has been told!

Comment: @Valkyriee No offence, but I'm not asking you :)

Comment: @DavidG none taken. you should explain him why bad things happen tho, to the best of your knowledge so others as well as me will learn more today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Clear Data within SQL here is the Query:

```
 DELETE FROM [TableName]
```

If you want to clear Data Within your application run this query using Entity Framework like below:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

The `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement is a fast, efficient method of deleting all rows in a table. `TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to the `DELETE` statement without a `WHERE clause`. However, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using `TRUNCATE TABLE`, it bypasses the log completely which will mess up database backups.

Comment: I try it by this command: 
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM __EFMigrationsHistories");

But i got this error: 
"no such table: __EFMigrationsHistories"

Comment: @Flo try `__MigrationHistory`

Comment: That was the correct table name: __EFMigrationsHistory

Comment: You can't use Truncate Table if there are FK pointing to it. Truncate table also initialises Identity values, which doesn't happen using Delete.